# InputStreamReader in doGet servlet

Tags: java, servlets, web, server-side

i am trying to send parameters (int and string) to servelet doGet method and use with InputStreamReader like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession UserSession = request.getSession();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        //Get all content from the buffer
        String bufferContent = br.readLine();
```

But for some resone its not working.
When I tried to use with doPost its work.

What can i do to solve it?

Comment: Do you at least realize that you try to open a `Reader` over a binary stream without even specifying the encoding? Also, the so-called performance advantages of `BufferedReader` are overhyped; in real life, its performance advantage is negligible, if not none (you _still_ have to go through the decoding process, after all)

Answer (score 1):

GET requests do not have an inputstream. They use the URL to send data